# Dynamically adding data in Hashmap to TableView in JavaFX

Tags: callback, javafx, hashmap, tableview

I have a map mapping symbols to prices.I want to display a table with one column containing keys and the other column containing corresponding values in JavaFX

```
public class myMap {
   Map<Symbol, Price> map;
 }
```

I want to display a table like the following
Symbol | Price

I guess it can be done by using TableView with CallBack.

Comment: Please go through http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm#CEGHGDFA

Answer (score 3):

Since I've already done something similar to this I'll add my code.

```
import java.util.Map;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.MapChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.ObservableMap;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.converter.NumberStringConverter;

public class MapTable extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        final ObservableMap<String, Number> obsMap = FXCollections.observableHashMap();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)  obsMap.put("key "+i, i*10d);

        final TableView<ObservableMap.Entry<String, Number>> tv = new TableView(FXCollections.observableArrayList(obsMap.entrySet()));
        tv.setEditable(true);

        obsMap.addListener((MapChangeListener.Change<? extends String, ? extends Number> change) -> {
            tv.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(obsMap.entrySet()));
        });

        TableColumn<ObservableMap.Entry<String, Number>,String> keyCol = new TableColumn<>("key");
        TableColumn<ObservableMap.Entry<String, Number>,Number> priceCol = new TableColumn<>("price");
        tv.getColumns().addAll(keyCol,priceCol);

        keyCol.setCellValueFactory((p) -> {
            return new SimpleStringProperty(p.getValue().getKey());
        });

        keyCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        keyCol.setOnEditCommit((TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Map.Entry<String,Number>, String> t) -> {
            final String oldKey = t.getOldValue();
            final Number oldPrice = obsMap.get(oldKey);
            obsMap.remove(oldKey);
            obsMap.put(t.getNewValue(),oldPrice);
        });

        priceCol.setCellValueFactory((p) -> {
            return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>(p.getValue().getValue());
        });

        priceCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(new NumberStringConverter()));
        priceCol.setOnEditCommit((TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Map.Entry<String,Number>, Number> t) -> {
            obsMap.put(t.getTableView().getItems().get(t.getTablePosition().getRow()).getKey(),//key
                       t.getNewValue());//val);
        });

        Button btn1 = new Button();
        btn1.setText("Add data");
        btn1.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
            obsMap.put("hi",100);
        });

        Button btn2 = new Button();
        btn2.setText("verify data");
        btn2.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
            for (Map.Entry<String,Number> me : obsMap.entrySet())
                System.out.println("key "+me.getKey()+" val "+me.getValue());
        });

        VBox root = new VBox(tv,btn1,btn2);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Map Table test");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this can help.

```
public class Demo {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

     // Use Java Collections to create the List.
     Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();

     // Now add observability by wrapping it with ObservableList.
    ObservableMap<String,String> observableMap = FXCollections.observableMap(map);
    observableMap.addListener(new MapChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(MapChangeListener.Change change) {
            System.out.println("Detected a change! ");
        }
    });

    // Changes to the observableMap WILL be reported.
    observableMap.put("key 1","value 1");
    System.out.println("Size: "+observableMap.size());

    // Changes to the underlying map will NOT be reported.
    map.put("key 2","value 2");
    System.out.println("Size: "+observableMap.size());

  }
}
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/collections/jfxpub-collections.htm